# Search Query don't show results

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a search engine but the problem is the search engine don't show search results, the connections to the database are correct here is the code:

**PHP :**

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tReference WHERE sReference LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("La Recherche est impossible");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);


if ($count == 0) {
    $output = "Aucun Résultat Pour Cette Recherche!";
              //English Trans : No results have been Found!

}
else 
{
        $sReference = $count['sReference'];
        $output.= '<div><ul><li><a target="_blanc" href="refrences.php?reference=' . $sReference . '" title="' . $sReference . '">' . $sReference . '</a></li></ul></div>';
}

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="searchd">
<div class="searchc">
<form action="reference.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" palceholder="Recherhcer...">
<input type="submit" Value="Ok">
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="output">
<?php echo ($output); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

And Thanks to All in advance!

Comment: You only get the count of rows, not the actual results. This is just a number, not an array. `$sReference = $count['sReference'];` will not work. You need [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to get the actual results. Or even better, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` ASAP.

Comment: @TomasCreemers it works, but I'm facing another problem which is is hows just one results not all the matching results

Comment: Shouldn't `"#[^0-9a-z]#i"` be `"/[^0-9a-z]/i"` ?

Comment: I think the first statement works with no problems

Comment: @SaifLacrimosa For one thing try changing it to `$searchq = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z]/i", "", $searchq);` I think what you have is incorrect.

Comment: @SaifLacrimosa: call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in a loop until it returns `false`. Each time you call it, it will return one row of the results. `while (false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))) { /* do stuff with $row */ }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- but I have another search engine with the same statement as above and it's working with no probs

Comment: @Fred-ii-: the start and end delimiter for a PCRE can actually be almost anything, see [PCRE: Delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: @TomasCreemers Yes, I just noticed it now. First time I see `preg_` like that. I Google'd it just now. That's why it was better said as a comment.

Comment: @SaifLacrimosa Won't fix your problem but change `palceholder` to `placeholder` and `Recherhcer` to `Rechercher` ;-)

Comment: @SaifLacrimosa Try this `preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"), "", ($searchq);` doesn't seem like you're closing your matches/queries correctly (parentheses), from what I found on PHP.net

Comment: the parentheses are correct, check the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not actually processing the result of your query.
You have to fetch each row from the returned result set and then use the fields returned in your html output.

Try this:-

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    $query = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM tReference 
         WHERE sReference LIKE '%$searchq%' OR 
               sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' OR 
               sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("La Recherche est impossible");

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        $output = "Aucun Résultat Pour Cette Recherche!";
              //English Trans : No results have been Found!
    } else {

        $output .= '<div><ul>';
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($query) ) {
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= '<a target="_blanc" href="refrences.php?reference=' . $row->sReference . '" '; 
            $output .= '" title="' . $row->sReference . '">' . $row->sReference . '</a>';
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul></div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

There was an error

Comment: I suggest you explain to the OP where he/she made a mistake, or what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: @SaifLacrimosa I fixed it when I saw it, you  must have copied it before I changed it. please re-copy and try again

Answer (score 0):

It's done Guys, Thanks to all here's the solution:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
$query = mysql_query(
"SELECT * FROM tReference 
WHERE sReference LIKE '%$searchq%' OR 
   sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' OR 
   sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("La Recherche est impossible");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
$output = "Aucun Résultat Pour Cette Recherche!";
} else {

$output .= '<div><ul>';
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {

$sReference = $row['sReference'];

$output .= '<li>';
$output .= '<a target="_blanc" href="refrences.php?reference="' . $sReference . '" '; 
$output .= '" title="' . $sReference . '">' . $sReference . '</a>';
$output .= '</li>';
}
$output .= '</ul></div>';
}

}
```

Thanks to *@RiggsFolly*, and Thanks to All of you.

Comment: Thanks. Dont be afraid of fetching the result as an object, its much easier to reference and understand.

Comment: "Another satisfied customer!" lol glad it worked out Saif, cheers ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, I've forget to returns the fetching as an object because I was Trying to fix it, and Fred -ii- thank you so much

Comment: @SaifLacrimosa You're quite welcome, I didn't do much but it's the "end result" that counts. (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. First I recommend that you use Object oriented PHP on a separate secure page. Then your code should look more like:

```
//secure.php
<?php
 function db(){
   return new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
 }
?>

//reference.php
include 'secure.php'; $output = '';
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
  $db = db(); $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  // What is this for? --->>> $searchq = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z]/i', "", $searchq);
   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tReference WHERE sReference LIKE '%$searchq%' || sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' || sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'");
   if($query->num_rows < 1){
     die('Aucun Résultat Pour Cette Recherche!');
   }
   else{
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
      $sref = $row['sReference'];
      $output.= "<li><a target='_blank' href='refrences.php?reference=$sref' title='$sref '>$sref</a></li>";
   }
   $query->free(); $db->close();
}
<div id='searchd'>
  <div class='searchc'>
    <form action='reference.php' method='post'>
      <input type='text' name='search' placeholder='Recherhcer...' />
      <input type='submit' value='Ok' name='sub' />
      <div class='clear'></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <ul id='output'><?php echo $output; ?></ul>
</div>
```